# OutOfMemoryException is ASP.Net application

Tags: out-of-memory

I am getting OOM exceptions in an ASP.Net application and have found that this is probably caused by heavy string operations such as `s1 = s1.Replace()` and `s1 = s1.SubString()` at the time where the exceptions are thrown.

Is it possible to get OOM exceptions just from those operations if they are happening sequentially? The number of requests are not a lot, but is it possible that the GC does not release memory in time before a new allocation on the heap is made?

In other words: can the following code give OOM exceptions or will the GC release the large amount of unreferenced strings before we get to OOM exception?

```
string s = "hello world";
while (true)
{
  s = s.Replace("h", "h");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question, more a suggestion of where to look if you want to debug difficult memory issues.

I've found [Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) an invaluable source of information on those hard to squash bugs. She uses Windbg, which has quite a steep learning curve - but it WILL allow you to work out what is taking up the memory and why.

I'd suggest starting with her [labs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx) if you are interested in debugging this, or maybe the [ASP.Net memory investigation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2007/08/13/asp-net-memory-investigation.aspx) post might set you on the right course